# Default date in alter table cannot be formatted

Tags: date, format, db2, locale

The date format of the default column in an alter table should be like timestamp or following the locale of the database server. I would like to know if this string representation could be formatted to another type. Let's suppose:

```
create table t1 (c2 int)
```

For example, this works because it is an ISO format:

```
alter table t1 add column c1 timestamp(12) default date('2014-11-13')
```

However, the following sentence should be executed with a USA locale, however, in other countries it is an invalid date, because there is not 13th month.

```
alter table t1 add column c1 timestamp(12) default date('11/13/2014')
```

And this is not possible neither, by passing the format function to the alter column statement:

```
alter table t1 add column c1 timestamp(12) default
  date(timestamp_format('13/11/2014','DD/MM/YYYY'))
```

Is there any way to customize this string, in order to understand the date format independently of the locale?

This is very important when delivering DDLs to recreate or apply patches for applications in different countries.

Comment: I don't understand the problem.  The date is stored in the DB without a format.  The literal '2014-11-13' is always interpreted as an ISO date YYYY-MM-DD.

Comment: I am not talking about date storage. I am asking about how to specify a default column with another date format different to ISO and database locale.

Comment: why?  what problem are you trying to solve?  If you're hand typing in the alter table it's up to you to know the locale you've got set.  If the alter table is being generated it should be generated with an ISO format so the locale doesn't matter.  If you don't want to worry about locale, then use ISO.

Comment: As noted in the first comment, the table doesn't store dates in **any** external format. The 'date' value in the database doesn't look like a 'date' at all. Assigning a format as a column attribute is meaningless. It's only when a value is displayed for a human to see on a screen or on a printed page or when a user types an input value that the format matters. It's an attribute of the user (or the process) that runs the application, not of the column. Therefore, you can't ALTER the column because the column doesn't have a format in the first place.

Comment: Notably, on the iSeries version of DB2, it's storing a counter for days (for the `DATE()` type).   Accessing this date is problematic.  The algorithim has a known bug: the year `300` is considered a leap-year (it's not).  If the system actually stored it as a formatted date, this would be quite impossible.  In general, data should never be stored formatted - that's a display-side problem.  When dealing (internally!) with date/time/timestamps, always use ISO formats, for inter-op reasons.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse On my i 6.1 system and one of my V5R3 systems, year 300 counted as having 365 days. They're all I checked. Regardless, I agree that ISO (and UTC) should always be what's handled by an application. The uses of formats, timezones, etc., should only come into the question at input/output points, and the user sets his/her own preferences.

Comment: @user2338816 - no, see, that's the weird thing; because of the way the algorithm problem manifests, there's still only 365 days.  Depending on how you access it, queries display it as February 29th.  But if you ask for a specific row, you need to use March 1st... (or was it the other way around).  You can't perform date-math on it (it complains about not being a valid date), but you can perform date math to get _into_ it.  I have no idea why IBM insists on using the algorithm (although, granted, there's little use for dates in western businesses that old...)

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse - Ah, makes more sense. Yeah, probably not much loan amortizations, ship dates, hire dates, etc., in AS/400 databases from back then. Makes me wonder who discovered it; also whether it actually interferes with anyone.